# Select combination of rows from a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Output should select scenarios (Col 1-5) which are a combination of Src X and any other one source (not X) based on Col3. Also, that one other source (not X) should have either  Y or NULL in Col 4 and Active in Col 5. Please note that if there are more than 2 rows based on Col3 (scenario 3 below) then we will not select that group. If Src X has  2 or more rows (along with a single non Src X) then that can be selected (Scenario 7). Only exception to above if there is a special Src Z with 'Y' in col 4 along with Src X and any other one source with NULL or Y in col 4 then that group is also to be selected. In below illustration Scenarios 1, 4 and 6, 7, 8 ,and 13 are to be selected from Table 1.

```
Table 1             
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4      Col5
1     Src A     100      Y       Active
2     Src X     100    NULL      Active
3     Src B     200     N        Active
4     Src X     200    NULL      Active
5     Src A     300     Y        Active
6     Src B     300     Y        Active
7     Src X     300    NULL      Active
8     Src D     400     Y        Active
9     Src X     400    NULL      Active
10    Src B     500     Y        Inactive
11    Src D     500     Y        Active
12    Src X     500    NULL      Active
13    Src C     600    NULL      Active
14    Src X     600    NULL      Active
15    Src A     700    Y         Active
16    Src X     700    NULL      Active
17    Src X     700    NULL      Active
18   Src A      800   NULL       Active
19   Src X      800   NULL       Active
20   Src Z      800    Y         Active
21   Src A      900   NULL       Active
22   Src X      900   NULL       Active
23   Src D      900   NULL       Active
24   Src A      1000  NULL       Active
25   Src X      1000  NULL       Active
26   Src Z      1000   N         Active
27   Src A      1100  NULL       Active
28   Src X      1100  NULL       Active
29   Src Z      1100  NULL       Active
30   Src P      1200  N          Active
31   Src Z      1200  Y          Active
32   Src X      1200  NULL       Active
33   Src A      1300  Y          Active
34   Src X      1300  NULL       Active
35   Src Z      1300  Y          Active
```

- Scenario 1 (rows : 1,2 based on  value in col 3 (100)) -Select
- Scenario 2(rows 3,4 based on  value in col 3 (200)) - Do not select since Col 4 is N for Src B
- Scenario 3 (rows 5,6,7 based on  value in col 3 (300)) -Do not select since there are 3 rows based on Col 3 and Col 5 ( value in col 4 here is not important)
- Scenario 4 ( rows 8,9 based on  value in col 3 (400))  -Select
- Scenario 5 (rows 10,11,12 based on  value in col 3 (500))- Select since just one other row aside from Src X based on Col 4 and Col 5 (active)
- Scenario 6 - (rows 13,14 based on  value in col 3 (600))- Select
- Scenario 7 - (rows 15,16,17 based on value in col 3 (700) - Select. Although 3 rows in this group but 2 are from Src X and all are active.
- Scenario 8 - (rows 18,19,20)  -select since Src A is NULL and Src Z is Y. Src Z = Y in Col4 is the only exception which is to be allowed with 3 rows. Note: Src X should always be present in each scenario.
- Scenario 9 - ( rows  21,22,23) -Do not select
- Scenario 10 - (rows 24,25,26)- Do not select
- Scenario 11 - (rows 27, 28, 29) - Do not select
- Scenario 12 - (rows 30,31, 32)- Do not select since Src Z is Y but Src P is N.
- Scenario 13 - (rows 33,34,35)- Select since Src A is Y and Src Z = Y. Src Z = Y in Col4 is the only exception which is to be allowed with 3 rows. Note: Src X should always be present in each scenario.
  Thanks in advance . Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why rows 5,6,7 are not selected, they seem to fit your original set of requirements

Comment: @Charlieface - rows 5,6,7 are not selected since we have 3 rows in this group (300 in col3 and all active) Essentially, looking for active groups of two  (based on col 3) one of which must be Src X

Comment: @DaleK-Understood. I removed Oracle but tagged it before since looking for SQL.

Comment: Your text at the top says "Output should select scenarios (Col 1-5) which are a combination of Src X and any other one source based on Col3. Also, that other source (not X) should have either Y or NULL in Col 4 and Col 5. In above illustration Scenarios 1, 4 and 6 are to be selected from table 1." which says nothing about three rows. You then say on these rows "since more than 3 rows" but they are exactly 3. Now you say "since we have 3 rows...looking for active groups of two" which seems to indicate you want to ignore `Inactive`. I suggest you make the requirements *much* clearer.

Comment: @Charlieface- Thanks for the edit suggestions. Hoping it's a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        sign(count(case when Col2  = 'Src X' then 1 end)
             over (partition by Col3)) as hasX,
        count(case when Col2 <> 'Src X' then 1 end)
             over (partition by Col3) as nonX
    from T
    where Col2 = 'Src X'
       or Col2 in (<src list> and coalesce(Col4, 'Y') = 'Y' and Col5 = 'Active'
)
select * from data
where hasX = 1 and nonX = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cbbdb41f5740848315bc0378d3f4c8a3

Comment: Thanks a lot. This gives excellent guidance. I am working to vet out the scenarios and will keep you posted.

Comment: One observation though : there are other values in col2 but I need to consider only Src A, Src B, Src C, Src D and not others like say Src E, F, etc. When I put these in the clause instead of <> Src X then the results appear to be inconsistent.

Comment: You probably want to add that condition to the second half of the `where`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was trying out a few different options but putting the source conditions i.e. col2='SrcX' or ( col2 in (SrcA,SrcB,SrcC,Src D) and coalesce (Col4, 'Y') = 'Y' )  is giving a list which has more than 2 rows when check in table (T). Maybe we need to put this outside the with clause. Also, I included Col5 = 'Active' in the hasX and nonX

Comment: @Avishek5 It's only considering rows that match all three conditions. I'm not sure that you scenarios really cover all the cases you've got.

Comment: @shawnt00- First of all, I really appreciate all your help and guidance.  I don't know why I am struggling but not able to come to the correct result set. The scenarios and all other conditions are okay. Just that we have a few other sources in the mix and I want the comparison with Src X to go against Src A, B, C and D.  and if we have a Src X and Src E combination then that needs to be excluded.

Comment: @Avishek5 The question does not indicate that Col4 or Col5 are relevant for Src X. I'm not really feeling that your problem description is complete.

Comment: @shawnt00- I agree it was not 100%.I got to know more as I was exploring the scenarios and edited the question to add in these scenarios. One more factor got added to the mix (Src Z) but the rest of the scenarios remains same. Now I am guessing this covers all and I am building on the initial idea . Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how Z is special. I don't know if P is special or what's significant about that case.

Comment: P is just another source (like A,B,C). Z is special when it has 'Y' in Col 4 because we are then  selecting that group although there are two records (Src A and Src X based on Col 3=1300; Src A also has a Y and this condition is still good) . In all other cases, we are selecting a record group which has one source (A,B, C ,P etc) and one  or more Src X.. Please see that we are not selecting col3=1200 although it has Src Z as 'Y' since P in that same group has a 'N'.